# Mapping of CiviCRM's Contact card fields to Drupal user entity's

Tags: drupal, contacts, civicrm-entity, field-mapping, sso

Essentially, we are having an integration problem where one component we are using is expecting to find or use default user entity fields, but these fields are not mapped into CiviCRM's user Contact card.

To be precise, we are using Drupal's LDAP module to exchange data with legacy systems and provide SSO auth. The LDAP module allows us to specify which Drupal user entity fields are mapped into the LDAP record using Drupal tokens, for example [field.field_lname], [field.field_fname], etc. However, those entity fields are not mapped into CiviCRM. As a result, we can't query their data using Civi, or expose it to users to edit using Civi's profile forms.

How can we manage mappings between CiviCRM's Contact record fields and Drupal's entity API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the way to sync drupal entities with CiviCRM fields is to enable the [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module.

Documentation can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2506765).